# What is the purpose of type definitions? When is it useful?

Tags: go

In golang you can define a type as a data structure

```
type MyMap map[int]int
mapper := make(MyMap)
```

and go on to use it like a regular map in go

```
mapper[13] = 133
```

But I don't understand when to use this or in what scenarios this will helpful?

Comment: Nothing in your question is about type aliases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a type alias (as the OP originally asked, before the question was edited).
That is a [type *definition*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions) or "**defined type**".

> A type definition creates a new, distinct type with the same underlying type and operations as the given type, and binds an identifier to it.

```
TypeDef = identifier Type .
```

That allows you to attach method on that type that you would not have been able to with the original type.

---

Type *alias* is part of the [Go 1.9 changes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#language).
It was [proposed here](https://github.com/golang/proposal/blob/master/design/18130-type-alias.md) and documented in [Code refactoring](https://talks.golang.org/2016/refactor.article).

> Go should add the ability to create alternate equivalent names for types, in order to enable gradual code repair during codebase refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

It is helpful when you wants to redeclare different parameters which are going to be `map[int]int`. Just when serving post request they use [url.Values{}](https://golang.org/src/net/url/url.go?s=22818:22849#L783) which is actually a map[string][]string.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    v := url.Values{}
    v.Set("name", "Ava")
    v.Add("friend", "Jess")
    v.Add("friend", "Sarah")
    v.Add("friend", "Zoe")
    // v.Encode() == "name=Ava&friend=Jess&friend=Sarah&friend=Zoe"
    fmt.Println(v.Get("name"))
    fmt.Println(v.Get("friend"))
    fmt.Println(v["friend"])
}
```